# ¿como buscar en un array dentro de otro array en una tabla? angular

Tags: angular

¿Cómo puedo buscar en el `array` de `let url of rowData.urls`? porque, al ser un `array` dentro de otro `array` en una tabla con el `input` de arriba, al buscar siempre muestra que no hay resultados y poniendo `{rowData[col.field]}}` en esa linea no muestra nada.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
          <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData" [pSelectableRowIndex]="rowIndex ">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
              <span *ngIf="col.field !=='URLS' && col.field !=='idPublicador'">{{rowData[col.field]}}</span>
              <span *ngIf="col.field=='URLS'">
                <div *ngFor="let url of rowData.urls | Filtering:searchTerm">
                  <p>{{rowData[col.field]}}</p>
                </div>
              </span>
              <span *ngIf="col.field =='idPublicador'">
                <p class="text-center">{{rowData[col.field]}}</p>
              </span>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage" let-columns>
          <tr>
            <td [attr.colspan]="columns.length">
              No se han encontrado registros.
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="paginatorleft">
          <div class="mostrar">
            <label class="mt-2 pr-3 registros-totales">Mostrando registros del {{table.first + 1}} al {{table.first + table.rows}} de un total de {{table.totalRecords}}</label>
            <label>{{'tabla.mensaje.mostrar' | translate}}</label>
            <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" [options]="rowsPerPage" (onChange)="onChangeRowsPerPages($event)"></p-dropdown>
            <label>{{'tabla.mensaje.registros' | translate}}</label>
          </div>
        </ng-template>

descripcion: "Superior a 768px"
idColegio: 7
idPublicador: 741
idframe: 3
nombreColegio: "ILUSTRE COLEGIO DE ABOGADOS DE CEUTA"
numeroFilas: 9
tipoPublicador: "WEB"
urls: Array(9)
0:
idUrl: 2611
valor: "10.75.29.132"
__proto__: Object
1: {idUrl: 2612, valor: "127.0.0.1"}
2:
idUrl: 2613
valor: "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"
__proto__: Object
3: {idUrl: 2614, valor: "10.74.88.137"}
4: {idUrl: 2615, valor: "10.74.88.137"}
5: {idUrl: 2616, valor: "10.74.88.84"}
6: {idUrl: 2617, valor: "10.74.212.86"}
7: {idUrl: 2618, valor: "10.75.29.132"}
8: {idUrl: 2619, valor: "10.74.247.5"}
```

Ahí está un ejemplo del `json` que imprimo por consola y yo quiero realizar búsquedas en tabla con el valor de las `urls`

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Deberías considerar el añadir un fragmento de código con tu array para que podamos ayudarte, si no sabemos como está hecho el array poco podremos ayudarte

Comment: @David ya puse una parte si necesitas más dimelo

Answer (score 0):

Hola @juan podrías compartir también el código del componente además del html. Puede que encuentres la solución en el operador spread('...') y previamente a el acceso hagas algo así:

```
Array1 = [ 1, 2, 4, Array2 ];
Array2 = [5, 6, 7];

Array1 = [1, 2, 4, ...Array2] = [ 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 ];
```

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.